# Apply CSS to div inside td tag

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to position the triangle over the table cell edge on both end. But half part of triangle is hidden. I tried to apply z-index as well but no impact. Can someone throw light what could go wrong here?

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Here is my Angular code

```html
<td *ngFor="let col of getNumberRange(1, maxDuration)" style="padding: 0;">
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <div *ngIf="col == 1" class="triangle-up"></div>
    <div *ngIf="col == 1" class="start-abbreviation">START</div>
    <div *ngIf="col == 5" class="end-abbreviation">END</div>
    <div *ngIf="col == 5" class="triangle-down"></div>
    <div *ngIf="col >= 1 && col <= 5" 
      style=" height: 15px; background-color: #1f4166; padding-top: 5px"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

```css
.triangle-up {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ff6600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.start-abbreviation {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999999999;
}

.triangle-down {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ff6600;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
}

.end-abbreviation {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999999999;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to the fact that the container does not have `overflow: visible` so we can just add the CSS to the parents, which will allow the arrow to be visible. Also made some extra CSS to make the output look like the screenshot!

css

```
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */
.triangle-up {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ff6600;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -4.5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.start-abbreviation {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999999999;
}

.triangle-down {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ff6600;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  right: -4.5px;
}

.end-abbreviation {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999999999;
}

.cell-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #1f4166;
  padding-top: 5px;
  min-width: 50px;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5nwv3u?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to adjust the top and bottom values for .triangle-up and .triangle-down respectively to ensure they align correctly with the edges of the table cell.

```css
.triangle-up {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ff6600;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;/*do correctly like this*/
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.start-abbreviation {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 99999999999;
}

.triangle-down {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #ff6600;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px; /*do correctly like this*/
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.end-abbreviation {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 99999999999;
}
```

```html
<td *ngFor="let col of getNumberRange(1, maxDuration)" style="padding: 0; position: relative;">
    <div *ngIf="col == 1" class="triangle-up"></div>
    <div *ngIf="col == 1" class="start-abbreviation">START</div>
    <div *ngIf="col == 5" class="end-abbreviation">END</div>
    <div *ngIf="col == 5" class="triangle-down"></div>
    <div *ngIf="col >= 1 && col <= 5" style="height: 15px; background-color: #1f4166; padding-top: 5px;"></div>
</td>
```